# Extending an endomorphism from a topological sub-ring to the topological ring

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, topological-rings

Let $A$ be a [topological ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring), let $B \subseteq A$ be a topological sub-ring, and let $f: B \to B$ be a continuous endomorphism of $B$.
Assume that (forgetting about the ring structure) $f$ can be extended to a continuous map $F: A \to A$, by some theorem from topology (with $B \subseteq A$ sets, not necessarily rings).

> Is it true that the fact that $B \subseteq A$ are topological rings (the addition and multiplication are continuous) guarantees that the extended continuous map $F$ is a ring endomorphism of $A$?

I think that the answer is yes (by continuity of the addition and multiplication).

Also, is it true that there are cases in which we can dismiss the assumption that $A$ is a topological ring, and just assume that it is a ring that has some topology (not necessarily compatible with addition and multiplication),
and still get that the extended continuous map $F$ is a ring endomorphism of $A$, for example, for a complete metric space $A$, $B$ dense in $A$, and $F(a):=\lim f(b_n)$,
where $\lim b_n=a$, because 
$F(aa'):= \lim f(b_nb_n')= \lim f(b_n)f(b_n')= \lim f(b_n) \lim f(b_n')= F(a)F(a')$, and similarly for addition.

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  Take $B=0$.  Then every continuous map $A\rightarrow A$ extends the only endomorphism $B\rightarrow B$, but certainly these wont be ring homomorphisms in general.

That you say "by some theorem from topology" suggests you want to assume more, in which case something along these lines might be true, but it's not clear what you intend.

Comment: @JonathanGleason, thanks for your remark. You understood me correctly, "by some theorem from topology", I certainly meant that I assumed more. There are some options for the additional assumption(s), for example, $A$ is a complete metric space, $B$ is dense in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is $T_0$ and complete, and $B$ is dense, then it's true, and follows from the following more general result.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be uniform spaces, let $D\subseteq X$, and let $f\colon D\rightarrow Y$ be uniformly-continuous.  Then, if $D$ is dense in $X$, and $Y$ is $T_0$ and complete, then there is a unique uniformly-continuous extension of $f$ to $X$.

Given a continuous endomorphism $f\colon B\rightarrow B$ (necessarily uniformly-continuous), under the stated assumptions, it extends to a unique uniformly-continuous function $F\colon A\rightarrow A$.  We need only check that $F$ itself is a ring homomorphism.  So, let $x,y\in A$.  Then, by density, there are nets $\lambda \mapsto x_{\lambda}\in B$ and $\lambda \mapsto y_{\lambda}\in B$ converge to $x$ and $y$ respectively (without loss of generality we can take their indexing sets to be the same).  Then,
$$
F(x+y)=F(\lim _{\lambda}x_{\lambda}+\lim _{\lambda}y_{\lambda})=F(\lim _{\lambda}(x_{\lambda}+y_{\lambda}))=\lim _{\lambda}F(x_{\lambda}+y_{\lambda})=\lim _{\lambda}f(x_{\lambda}+y_{\lambda})=\lim _{\lambda}[f(x_{\lambda})+f(y_{\lambda})]=\lim _{\lambda}f(x_{\lambda})+\lim _{\lambda}f(y_{\lambda})=F(x)+F(y).
$$
Similarly for multiplication.

Comment: Thanks!! You generalized the example I mentioned above (from metric spaces to uniform spaces, from sequences to nets/filters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Cauchy_nets). Please, can your answer be further generalized? In particular, do you think that it is possible to apply here the ideas of the second answer of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775510/given-a-continuous-function-f-s-rightarrow-y-of-topological-spaces-when-can?rq=1

Comment: @user237522 I think that these two sorts of extensions are of quite a different nature, and I don't see how ideas here could be applied there or vice-versa.  One big difference, for example, is that the conditions here are sufficient for the existence of a *unique* extension, whereas in the other answer, the primary concern is whether any extension *exists* at all.

Comment: I see (actually, the existence is what is more important to me). Please, is it possible to find a similar extension to that in your answer, but without requiring the completeness of $Y$? There is a theorem of Taimanov with $Y$ Compact or Hausdorff http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-054-01/S0002-9939-1976-0390999-0/S0002-9939-1976-0390999-0.pdf (Theorem 1) but one has to check that condition (2) is satisfied.

Comment: No, it's not true if $Y$ is not complete.  For example, take $X:=[0,1]$, $Y:=(0,1)$, $D:=(0,1)$, and $D\rightarrow Y$  the inclusion.

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, I am more interested in the case $X=Y$, but probably it is possible to find a counter-example in that case too (if it does not satisfy additional conditions).